# Server side Access token from one time code coming from Android Application

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-java-client

How do I get an access token when I've got an one time code coming from an Android application?

More specifically:

1. On the Google API Console when creating config for an Android app there is not client secret. What do you set the client secret to when doing this? Some have suggested that I leave this blank..
2. What do I make the redirect uri?

I'm keen to use the google api's to do this work rather than hand coding the request.

That is the `com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest`

This is my sample code:

```
private void getAccessToken(String oAuthGoogleClientId, String oAuthGoogleClientSecret, String one_time_code) throws IOException {
    HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
    GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, oAuthGoogleClientId, oAuthGoogleClientSecret, one_time_code, "postmessage").execute();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to create an OAuth2 client for your web server in the same project of the one for the Android app.

To obtain an offline authorization code, you can call GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() from your Android app with a special "scope" string:

`oauth2:server:client_id:<web_client_id>:api_scope:<scope1> <scope2>`.

Then you send the auth code to your server and your server performs the [OAuth2 Web Server flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#handlingtheresponse) to exchange the code for a refresh/access token by using the client_id and client_secret of the web server OAuth2 client.
You can find more information in the [cross client auth document](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth).

Comment: Yes, thanks. I thought I was getting a one time code but I was actually getting a Id Token. I discovered this when I sent the token for decoding to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=